# Is force necessary for angular acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, rotational-kinematics

Suppose a body is moving with uniform velocity in the plane along a straight line $y=a$.  We can calculate its angular velocity to be $\omega = v \sin^2 \theta / a$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the body's position vector and the $x$-axis.

However, the angle is changing, so there is angular acceleration.  Can a body have angular acceleration when no force acts on it?

[image: calculating the result of angular velocity about origin]

Comment: $\tau=r\times \vec F$ and $\vec \tau =I\vec \alpha$

Comment: the body only undergoes acceleration if either the magnitude or direction of the velocity vector changes.

Comment: The conserved quantity is angular momentum. 1) It's important to follow the meaning of the words, as colloquial expressions usually will not lead to good physics. In physics, usually and equation will clear things up. In this case, "angular acceleration" isn't very clear.  2) Even so, one can have angular acceleration without an applied force (or torque, which would be the more precise phrasing), eg, when a spinning figure skater moves their arms in or out.

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum, $\mathbf L$, of a particle P about a fixed point O is defined by
$$\mathbf L = \mathbf r \times m\mathbf v$$
in which $\mathbf r$ is the displacement vector OP and $\mathbf v$ is the particle's velocity.

So the magnitude of the angular momentum of the particle about O is simply
$$L=mva=\text{constant}.$$
The direction is also constant.
These accord with there being no torque on the particle, as no force is acting on it.

And yet, according to your (correct) formula for $\omega$, the angular velocity (rate of change of $\theta$) keeps changing as $\theta$ changes.

There's nothing contradictory about these statements. Although we can express the particle's angular momentum in terms of $\omega$, the relationship also involves the changing distance OP. In fact
$$L=mav =ma^2 \text{cosec}^2 \theta\ \omega = m r^2 \omega.$$